# Procedural extrusion from an object

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes, objects, bezier-curves, geometry

I am trying to find a way to create procedural extrusions of an object. Assume our base object is a manifold object with a curved surface, such as a sphere (Fig 1). I would like to use a Curve object or similar to create an outline which is snapped to the object's surface (Fig 2). Is there any procedural way or workflow, to use this outline to create an extrusion of the base object? (Fig 3 for approximate result). I would like to have a procedural/reversible workflow so I can adjust the outline afterwards if necessary.

Any proposed workflow is allowed (Geometry Nodes, Modifiers, coding, ...).

[image: Fig 1][image: Fig 2][image: Fig 3]

Answer (score 5):

You could use geometry nodes for this

[image]

Basically, project the curve on the surface, copy the surface normals, convert the curve to a mesh with a simple curve line and use it to cut the sphere and get the faces inside the curve. Then, extrude this new surface

I am using blender 4.1 for the set curve normal node to work as intended

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about how to do so with a curve, but a possibility to achieve the same result would be to use a displacement map for the object with a setup like this :

[image]

[image]

This way you can just draw the shape you want to "extrude" in texture paint mode. It require a lot of geometry though. Hope this helps.